# Remove similar Strings in Python List by Levenshtein Ratio

Tags: python, string, list, iteration, levenshtein-distance

I am trying to remove similar words in a python List by calculating the Levenshtein ratio between them. If the ratio is >0.9 the word should be removed. So I have to create a loop that iterates through the list and compare each word with each other word and then remove them if the ratio is to high. Unfortunately I haven't quite figured out how to implement that in python, since I cannot iterate through a list and remove its contents. My first naive idea was sth. like the code seen below, which doesn't work, since it skips half the elements. Any help would be appreciated.

```
word_list = ['asf', 'bcd', 'ase', 'cdf', 'asl']
```

The Goal here would be to remove the elements 'ase' and 'asl' because they are similar to 'asf'
My first attempt looked like this:

```
for word in word_list:
    for x in word list:
       if Levenshtein.ratio(word, x) >= 0.9:
          word_list.remove(word)
```

Comment: Instead use list_comprehension and convert to set to remove duplicates ?

Comment: @schieslu. Typo error: for x in word list: Should be for x in word_list:. Missed underscore

Answer (score 0):

using `difflib` you can match the similar strings in a list. and then remove the similar strings.

```
import difflib

word_list = ['asf', 'bcd', 'ase', 'cdf', 'asl']

close_match = difflib.get_close_matches('asf', word_list)
close_match.remove('asf')

result = []
for i in word_list:
    if i not in close_match:
        result.append(i)
print(result)

>>> ['asf', 'bcd', 'cdf']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like below:

```
# Output list
output = []

for word in word_list:
    for x in word_list:
        # Change our logic, and look for values below 0.9 - Then add those to our output list
       if not Levenshtein.ratio(word, x) >= 0.9 and (word not in output):
          output.append(word)
```

Comment: Typo error: for x in word list: Should be for x in word_list:. Missed underscore